# XML - Access content between two self-closing tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

Say I have the following XML file

```
<someElements>
    <element 1 /> Some content, relevant to this element, etc.
    <element 2 /> Some more content, relevant to this element, etc.
    <element 3 /> Some other content, relevant to this element, etc.
    <element 4 /> Some different content, relevant to this element, etc.
    <element 5 /> Some last content, relevant to this element, etc.
</someElements>
```

I now want to access, say, the content of element no. 3. How could I do this with nodejs / javascript? I have tried different parsers / libraries, which give me the content of something which is wrapped e.g.

```
<element> content </element>
```

- but none of them enables me to access the content between two self-closing elements (or: they probably **do** have that functionality, but I haven't been able to find it yet)

Comment: _“I now want to access, say, the content of element no. 3”_ – that element **does not have** any content. What you have here, is plain simple _text nodes_ that are children of the parent element, `someElements` - and siblings of the other, actual elements. So get access to the element 3 node, and then access its next sibling.

Comment: It sounds like the XML should be redesigned so that they aren't self-closing elements and the content relating to them is child nodes of that element.

Comment: I agree, but that's the document I was given and I need to work with it.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, yes that makes sense. How can I access a sibling of an XML element in javascript / nodejs though? What parser would be best suited for this, I cannot find any that offer this functionality

Comment: Any standard DOM library should provide something like a nextSibling property on the basic node element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling

Comment: This is no XML at all !  `<element 1 />` is **not** valid XML. You are left with using Regex

Comment: really, - is it not? Can I still use the solution of @CBroe?

Comment: Correct, it would not be valid XML, if your element names actually contained spaces ... I assumed that was just an quick example, but that in reality you are dealing with well-formed XML.

Comment: so how can I access now what is to the right of each child element?

Comment: Also, people [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-XML) & [here (w3.org)](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752199/xml-milestones-or-elements-that-cross-other-elements) seem to disagree that self-closing elements aren't valid XML - which leaves me confused (?)